# How to get JSON hierarchy correspoding to key in java

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a JSON structure like this :

```
{
    "cars": {
        "Nissan": [
            {"model":"Sentra", 
             "doors":4},
            {"model":"Maxima", 
             "doors":4}
        ],
        "Ford": [
            {"model":"Taurus", 
             "doors":4},
            {"model":"Escort", 
             "doors":4}
        ]
    }
}
```

I will enter key , output should print entire path till that key. 
**For example** :
**For Nissan ,first array:**

```
Input :model , Output:cars->Nissan[0].model<br/>
Input:doors ,  Output:cars->Nissan[0].doors<br/>
```

**For Nissan ,second array:**

```
Input :model , Output:cars->Nissan[1].model<br/>
```

So, like that I want full path for every JSON field.
I tried Jackson framework to achieve this, but got no success.
Please help..

Comment: Nissan first array and second array, input and output both are same ?

Comment: How you gonna use this output?

Comment: If you want to get values from json via paths, I think you can try jayway jsonpath library. Check the link please https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath.

Comment: @eg04lt3r: Actually I want to retrieve mapping of each node present in json.The reason being if the user want to fetch any particular node, he use this mapping directly.

Comment: @eg04lt3r :Thanks for the link, But Jayway also uses JSON paths to retrieve values.I want to generate that json path for each node present in the json. For e.g like this  **$.store.book[*].author**

Comment: @eg04lt3r  : I came across this question **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33224048/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-all-json-paths-to-values-from-a-json-string** , it's similar to my requirement .But I cannot run this code on my machine .

Comment: @eg04lt3r       : Any suggestions ?

Comment: @mayankbisht, do you use any build tool for your project? If yes seems like you should provide missed dependency from maven repo https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20170516. If no, you can download missed jar from the same page and add it to classpath of your application.