# Need explanation with this post

Tags: java, json

**I want to save JSON path for each JSON node in a list**.
I came across this tutorial :**[How do I get a list of all JSON paths to values from a JSON String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33224048/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-all-json-paths-to-values-from-a-json-string?noredirect=1&lq=1)** ,
 but I am unable to understand & execute it
Please help..

Code:

```
String json = "{'shopper': {'Id': '4973860941232342', 'Context': {'CollapseOrderItems': false, 'IsTest': false } }, 'SelfIdentifiersData': {'SelfIdentifierData': [{'SelfIdentifierType': {'SelfIdentifierType': '111'} }, {'SelfIdentifierType': {'SelfIdentifierType': '2222'} } ] } }";

Configuration conf = Configuration.defaultConfiguration();
List<String> jsonPaths = JsonPath.using(conf).parse(json).read("$");

for (String path : jsonPaths) {
    System.out.println(path);
}
```

Expected Output:

```
$.shopper.Id
$.shopper.Context.CollapseOrderItems
$.shopper.Context.IsTest
$.SelfIdentifiersData[0].SelfIdentifierData.SelfIdentifierType.SelfIdentifierType
$.SelfIdentifiersData[1].SelfIdentifierData.SelfIdentifierType.SelfIdentifierType
```

Exception trace :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/minidev/json/writer/JsonReaderI
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.DefaultsImpl.<init>(DefaultsImpl.java:17)
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.DefaultsImpl.<clinit>(DefaultsImpl.java:15)
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.Configuration.getEffectiveDefaults(Configuration.java:53)
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.Configuration.defaultConfiguration(Configuration.java:178)
    at com.json.JsonPathCreator.main(JsonPathCreator.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.minidev.json.writer.JsonReaderI
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: Share your code what you have tried until now

Comment: what is the requirement are you trying achieve?

Comment: @RajithPemabandu :My requirement is to store all JSON node paths into list. 
Like this :  $.shopper.Id
$.shopper.Context.CollapseOrderItems
$.shopper.Context.IsTest
$.SelfIdentifiersData[0].SelfIdentifierData.SelfIdentifierType.SelfIdentifierType
$.SelfIdentifiersData[1].SelfIdentifierData.SelfIdentifierType.SelfIdentifierType

Comment: have you used the `JsonParser` class which is used in the post you have shared.

Comment: @RajithPemabandu : Yes, I tried above mentioned tutorial , but i am getting  **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/minidev/json/writer/JsonReaderI**  exception.

Comment: it would be helpful if you can post the full stack-trace.

Comment: @RajithPemabandu :Added exception trace.

Comment: From your error log it seems you are missing dependencies in your classpath

Comment: @Akshay : yes, I tried adding missing jars into my project, but still throwing same exception.

Comment: The best way to deal with classnotfound exception is try importing/atleast finding that class from the jar file..try doing that manually first..in that package net/minidev/json/writer/ there must be a class named JsonReaderI..if not try changing versions

Answer (score 1):

Use this dependency for JsonReaderI.
[json-smart-2.1.0](http://central.maven.org/maven2/net/minidev/json-smart/2.1.0/json-smart-2.1.0.jar)